# ADO.Entities fulltext support

Tags: c#, ado.net

I was using Linq to SQL and it didn't have any FULL-TEXT support. 
I went back to Stored procedure.

The second reson was because stored procedure is almost 3 times slower.

I would like to know if the performance is better for ADO.Entities and if has support for fulltext search

---

I mean that Stored procedure is 3 times faster then Linq to SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq to SQL and ADO.Entities won't be faster than using the equivalent Stored Procedures, although the performance difference will probably be negligible in most instances. ADO.Entities generally won't perform faster than LINQ to SQL either, but once again, in most instances, it won't be slower.

ADO.Entities does not support FullText search yet. I would continue to use Stored Procedures for that functionality if I were you.